# Using recyclerview for a short list of items, do not want to remove or reuse items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, baseadapter, android-adapterview

I have to use a Recyclerview but for such a small number of items it doesn't make sense to recycle views.  It would be better to just add new views into the list and let them stay in the view heirachy.  Are there settings that would allow this?

Comment: You could try [RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool#setMaxRecycledViews()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool#setMaxRecycledViews(int,int)) and set the max to the number of items of a type that you have. Depending upon your design, you could also just place the views into a _ScrollView_.

Answer (score 0):

I guess setting RecyclerView height to "wrap_content" would work just fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).